# Spring OAuth2 Resource Server - user-name-attribute not reflected in SecurityContextHolder

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a claim named `user_name` within my JWT and also corresponding `user-name-attribute` set as `user_name` in spring security oauth2 client provider proper property:

`spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-oauth-provider.user-name-attribute=user_name`

I can also see this property is properly being read by `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` class (`ClientRegistration.ProviderDetails.UserInfoEndpoint`). But when I read `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()` **on Resource Server** I can see the value taken from (default) `sub` - `IdTokenClaimNames.SUB` claim.

Why is that? Do I still miss some additional configuration also on resource server side to have specified `user-name-attribute` taken and returned by `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()` on Resource Server? I understand that only Bearer token (and maybe some cookies) is being sent from client to resource server so maybe also some other filter is needed on Gateway/client side - just guessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are using a property prefixed with `security.oauth2.client`, which is intended for OAuth 2.0 Clients.

In Spring Security 5.2.x, there is no Spring Boot property to indicate a user name attribute to Resource Server, e.g. `security.oauth2.resourceserver.xyz`

You could publish your own `Converter` to the DSL, though:

```java
JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();

http
    .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt -> {
            JwtAuthenticationToken authentication = converter.convert(jwt);
            return new JwtAuthenticationToken(authentication.getToken(), 
                    authentication.getAuthorities(), jwt.getClaim("claim"));
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - just added casting to `JwtAuthenticationToken` and it works fine. I added further thoughts on that issue on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7757 mostly around the idea of having `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.user-name-attribute` also on resourceserver side so it is being hanlded automatically with kind of consistency on both (client and resource server ends). Thanks again!